# Is the airplane scene in this game?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

At 0:52 of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuzaxlddWbk) there is a scene where the vet and noob are in free fall due to a crashing airplane.  Is there a level in this game where this takes place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. It's in the [fouth mission called "Turbulence"](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Turbulence) where you're playing a russian agent and have to protect the russian president and his daughter.
The weightlessness only lasts a few moments, but it's gameplay and not a video: you're able to fly around (limited), reload and shoot.